# Bandpass Experiment: Weird graph! amplitude mismatch?

Tags: filters, filter-design, spectrogram, downsampling

Why is this generic BP filter seem to magnifying amplitudes when I run it at lower sample rates? The bass range seems to 32 times louder at 1275 Hz *(44.1 kHz / 32)* than at 44.1kHz?

Here is a graph of a birdsong which has been passed through 128 BandPass filters on MIDI notes 0 to 128.

To make the graph draw faster, I have attempted an experiment: skip 32 audio samples for frequencies lower than 150HZ.

The filter-bank draws 15 times faster, but the results are wrong: the frequencies lower than 150Hz seem to have been multiplied by an amplitude of 32? What is happening?

[image]
correct graph:
[image]
The same downsampling method doesn't amplify a sine sweep, so I think it will not be possible to use this computation optimizing trick for a high quality spectrogram?
[image]